# Fix (force) loop to protect/unprotect/hide/show worksheets

Tags: excel, vba

Before beginning I would like to thank anyone who offers any suggestions since this will be a long post. I will include all the details in my code so someone can help me notice what I am missing and/or doing wrong. I am creating an Excel workbook that will be used to register sales and spendings using a variety of macros working through `userforms`. In order to protect the documented and determine who added what, I designed a login system using [this video](https://youtu.be/0ahYoy5L3ec) as a guide but with some refinements to the code I did myself.

[image]
So this is basically how the login system works. On a `worksheet` named `Users` I created two tables. The first one is named `LoginRegistry` (the blue one in the image) and the second one is named `Users` (the green one in the image). The headers in the table `Users` from the column `HOME` to `USERS` have the exact same name as the worksheets on the workbook do. They are also in the exact same order. When you double click on any of the cells within that range they loop through three icons (that are just using the `Webdings` font colored accordingly). The green icon makes the sheet visible and editable, the blue one makes it visible but protected and the red one hides it and protects it (a bit overkill but I liked to do this just in case there are any vulnerabilities). The `ALL` column changes all of the permissions at once. The code for this is the following:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)

  'Change icons when double clicking
  Set UserPermissions = Worksheets("Users").Range("Users[[ALL]:[USERS]]")
  UserPermissionsRange = UserPermissions.Address(0, 0)
  If Not Intersect(Target, Range(UserPermissionsRange)) Is Nothing Then
  
    'Change from empty to unlocked
    If Target.Value = Empty Then
      Target.Font.Color = RGB(0, 176, 80)
      Target.Value = "Ð"
      Cancel = True
    
    'Change from unlocked to read only
    ElseIf Target.Value = "Ð" Then
      Target.Font.Color = RGB(48, 84, 150)
      Target.Value = "N"
      Cancel = True
    
    'Change from read only to locked
    ElseIf Target.Value = "N" Then
      Target.Font.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
      Target.Value = "Ï"
      Cancel = True
    
    'Change from locked to unlocked
    ElseIf Target.Value = "Ï" Then
      Target.Font.Color = RGB(0, 176, 80)
      Target.Value = "Ð"
      Cancel = True
      
    End If
    
  Else
    Exit Sub
  
  End If
  
  'Modify all of the permissions at once
  If Target.Column = 10 Then
    AllWorksheetPermissions = "K" & Target.Row & ":" & "R" & Target.Row
    Range(AllWorksheetPermissions) = Target.Value
    Range(AllWorksheetPermissions).Font.Color = Target.Font.Color
    
  End If

End Sub
```

The `userform` that captures the information when logging in is named `frmLoginForm`. Each time the workbook opens the following code is executed:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

  'Hide anything other than the form from the user
  Application.Visible = False
  'Show the worksheet that has all the information of the user permissions
  Sheets("Users").Visible = -1
  'Show login form to capture the user information
  frmLoginForm.Show

End Sub
```

This way the user can not do anything before authenticating. The form has two textboxes, two buttons and three labels. It is the following:

[image]

The code behind the form is:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

  'Set custom colors to the form objects
  frmLoginForm.BackColor = RGB(240, 235, 215)
  cmdLogin.BackColor = RGB(201, 34, 23)
  cmdExit.BackColor = RGB(201, 34, 23)
  cmdLogin.ForeColor = vbWhite
  cmdExit.ForeColor = vbWhite

End Sub


Private Sub UserForm_QueryClose(Cancel As Integer, CloseMode As Integer)

  'Close the workbook whether the user closes the form with the "Exit button" or
  'clicking the "X" icon in the top right corner
  If CloseMode = vbFormControlMenu Then
    Cancel = True
    Unload frmLoginForm
    ThisWorkbook.Close

  End If

End Sub


Private Sub cmdLogin_Click()

  'Look for the valid user range
  Set UserRangeLookUp = Worksheets("Users").Range("Users[[USER]:[PASSWORD]]")
  
  On Error Resume Next
  'Find correct password
  CorrectPassword = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(tbxUser.Value, UserRangeLookUp, 2, 0)
  
  If Err.Number = 1004 Then
  MsgBox "The user you entered does not exist."
  Err.Clear
  Else
  
    If StrComp(tbxPassword.Value, CorrectPassword, vbBinaryCompare) = 0 Then
      
      'Make worksheet visible
      Application.Visible = True
      
      'Only add a new row to the LoginRegistry table if it is empty
      If (Range("Users!B3").Value) = "" Then
      Else
        Worksheets("Users").ListObjects("LoginRegistry").ListRows.Add
      End If

      'Find the last row of the LoginRegistry (adding +2 to get the absolute reference)
      Set LoginRegistryRange = Worksheets("Users").Range("LoginRegistry")
      LoginRegistryLastRow = LoginRegistryRange.Rows.Count + 2
      
      'Last row of each column
      UserLastRow = "Users!" & "B" & LoginRegistryLastRow
      DateLastRow = "Users!" & "C" & LoginRegistryLastRow
      TimeLastRow = "Users!" & "D" & LoginRegistryLastRow
      
      'Save the information of the current login to the LoginRegistry 
      Range(UserLastRow).Value = tbxUser.Value
      Range(DateLastRow).Value = Format(Date, "dd/mm/yyyy")
      Range(TimeLastRow).Value = Format(Time, "hh:mm:ss")
      
      'Protect/unprotect/hide/show worksheets according to the user permissions
      Set UserListRangeLookup = Worksheets("Users").Range("Users[USER]")
      ActiveUserRow = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(tbxUser.Value, UserListRangeLookup, 0) + 2
      
      'Loop through the columns `HOME` to `USERS` in the table `Users`. The headers containing
      'the worksheet names to reference are in the second row of this worksheet
      'Ð means unlocked and visible, N means locked and visible, Ï locked and not visible
      For i = 11 To 18
        If Cells(ActiveUserRow, i).Value = "Ð" Then
          Sheets(Cells(2, i).Value).Unprotect "123456"
          Sheets(Cells(2, i).Value).Visible = -1
        ElseIf Cells(ActiveUserRow, i).Value = "N" Then
          Sheets(Cells(2, i).Value).Protect Password:="123456"
          Sheets(Cells(2, i).Value).Visible = -1
        ElseIf Cells(ActiveUserRow, i).Value = "Ï" Then
          Sheets(Cells(2, i).Value).Protect Password:="123456"
          Sheets(Cells(2, i).Value).Visible = 2
        End If
      Next i
      
      'Show "HOME" worksheet first always
      Sheets("HOME").Activate
      
      'Close login form
      Unload frmLoginForm
    
    Else
      MsgBox "Incorrect password. Try again."
    
    End If
  
  End If


End Sub

Private Sub cmdExit_Click()

  'Code for the exit button on the form
  Unload frmLoginForm
  ThisWorkbook.Close

End Sub
```

So, once I have explained all of this I can focus on my issue. The thing is that the permissions are not always right. I am unable to find the exact situation when the code gets bugged, but sometimes when you login the user credentials are verified but the nothing is updated on the workbook. A user that is supposed to only see a few worksheets remains with all the permissions of the admin user if he logged previously, for example. And most of the time, once the code is broken it will not work again until I change one of the permissions of the logged user in the table `Users`. No matter how many times I try to login, if no change is made to the permissions they will not change, and the worksheets will remain with the permissions of the last user that could log in properly.

At first I thought the issue was because the worksheet with the permissions was set to **very hidden** and the macro could not read the data, but even if I put it to the end and make it visible again every time the workbook is opened the issue keeps happening.

Right now, I believe the loop is my problem, but I just can not find out what is wrong. The loop is the following (it is exactly what I showed in the previous code extract, I am just copying it again so you can focus on this part of the code):

```
  'Loop through the columns `HOME` to `USERS` in the table `Users` (col 11 to 18). The headers
  'containing the worksheet names to reference are in the second row of this worksheet
  'Ð means unlocked and visible, N means locked and visible, Ï locked and not visible
      For i = 11 To 18
        If Cells(ActiveUserRow, i).Value = "Ð" Then
          Sheets(Cells(2, i).Value).Unprotect "123456"
          Sheets(Cells(2, i).Value).Visible = -1
        ElseIf Cells(ActiveUserRow, i).Value = "N" Then
          Sheets(Cells(2, i).Value).Protect Password:="123456"
          Sheets(Cells(2, i).Value).Visible = -1
        ElseIf Cells(ActiveUserRow, i).Value = "Ï" Then
          Sheets(Cells(2, i).Value).Protect Password:="123456"
          Sheets(Cells(2, i).Value).Visible = 2
        End If
      Next i
```

I would greatly appreciate any suggestion you may have.

Comment: You never cancel the `On Error Resume Next` so it's possible there's an untrapped error later in your code.  You should always use OERN as little as possible, and cancel it using `On Error Goto 0` as soon as possible.

Comment: @TimWilliams Super Symmetry found the issue in my code and was able to fix it. However, your suggestions is very helpful. That's something I didn't consider before. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Potential Solution**

Just by skimming through your code and looking at your highlighted loop (at the end), there's a serious issue (simple but serious): You are **not** qualifying the `Cells()` references. Therefore, it is checking values of `Cells(ActiveUserRow, i)` of the active sheet, which I assume is not the USERS sheet, which you had just made visible when the workbook was open. *You do **not** need to make this sheet visible by the way and VBA will have no problem to access it when it is `xlSheetVeryHidden`*

The first thing you should do is qualify these references. Comment if this doesn't work, so that I can dig a little deeper in your code.

```
      With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("USERS")
        For i = 11 To 18
          If .Cells(ActiveUserRow, i).Value = "Ð" Then
            Sheets(.Cells(2, i).Value).Unprotect "123456"
            Sheets(.Cells(2, i).Value).Visible = -1
          ElseIf .Cells(ActiveUserRow, i).Value = "N" Then
            Sheets(.Cells(2, i).Value).Protect Password:="123456"
            Sheets(.Cells(2, i).Value).Visible = -1
          ElseIf .Cells(ActiveUserRow, i).Value = "Ï" Then
            Sheets(.Cells(2, i).Value).Protect Password:="123456"
            Sheets(.Cells(2, i).Value).Visible = 2
          End If
        Next i
      End With
```

*End of solution*

**Update** (following comments):

- I never had any issues with accessing cells in a `xlSheetVeryHidden` worksheet, whether in VBA or excel formulae. I have to say I don't know. I tested this with

```
Sub TestHiddenSheets()
    With Sheets("Sheet1")
        .Visible = xlSheetVeryHidden
        .Cells(1, 1) = 1
        .Protect
        Debug.Print .Cells(1, 1)
        .Visible = xlSheetVisible
    End With
    With Sheets("Sheet2")
        .Visible = xlSheetHidden
        .Cells(1, 1) = 2
        .Protect
        Debug.Print .Cells(1, 1)
        .Visible = xlSheetVisible
    End With
End Sub
```

- Try to get in the habbit of qualifying **all** your ranges. In fact you should almost never write `Range` or `Cells` without a `.` before them.

Your code is clearly well structured and the logic is very clear, well done for that. However, allow me to point out a few opportunities of improvement

- The convensional way to qualify a range is `Sheets("ShtName").Range("A1")` not `Range("ShtName!A1")`. Although both work, the former makes your code much more readable and there's no ambiguity about whether the range was qualified or not. I have a feeling that this style of yours is the reason you did not spot the bug in your code. As soon as I saw `Range` and `Cells` in your code without `.` I stopped reading everything else and just followed the qualifications (or lack of) of these ranges.
- Always use enumerations rather than litteral values. For example your should use `Sheet.Visible = xlSheetVisible` instead of `Sheet.Visible = -1`
- I second the point made by @TimWilliams in his comment. Also instead of `Resume Next`, you could use `GoTo ErrorHandler` where you inform the user that the name was not found.
- I would use `Match` ranther than `VLookup`. That way you wouldn't have to sort your table alphabetically.
- A combo box is a better option for the user name instead of a text box.
- In the `cmdExit_Click()` sub I would also close the workbook.
- Try as much as possible not to hard code values in your code. Values such as `"Ð"`, `RGB(,,)`, passwords should be either local/public variables or even enumerations.

Comment: You are just brilliant! I can't believe I didn't noticed that. After some `Debug.Print` testing I could verify the issue was that my loop wasn't getting any value if the worksheet wasn't activate. I'll mark your answer as the solution. Also, could you please give me a little more information about the VBA code being able to access a `xlSheetVeryHidden`? I found this article (and a few more) saying that you can't do it that way. Is there something I'm missing or are those straight misleading? [link](https://excelribbon.tips.net/T009329_Running_Macros_on_Hidden_Worksheets.html)

Comment: I read the article and I am a big fan of this website. However, I don't ever remember having a problem accessing cells in a `xlSheetVeryHidden` sheet. Try not to unhide your USERS sheet and see if it works (please let us know the outcome).

Comment: I have been testing the code for a few hours in different situations and it seems to be working fine, whether the sheets are hidden or showing, when properly qualifying the range used by the loop. I also fixed my code will all your suggestions, I believe it is bullet-proof now. Thank you very much for taking the time to help. Have a good day!